# How to insert some space after multiple strings so they all got the same length?

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I want to get a string in C# like `"Charlotte: Female\nChris: Male"` which is printed out as:

```
Charlotte: Female
Chris: Male
```

And now I want the Male and Female to start at the same column looking like:

```
Charlotte:  Female
Chris:      Male
```

I tried with `PadRight`, but since all the characters differ in width (for example 'i' is small while 'A' is very large) this doesn't work for me (The result looks like +/- 2 spaces difference). 
Is there any way to get strings to a fixed width?

Comment: How/where are you printing them out such that they are getting displayed with a proportional font (as opposed to monospaced)?  This is not a `Console.WriteLine`, because the terminal is usually monospaced.  Do you mean that these are being displayed on a Windows Form or something?  Please clarify how these are "printed out".

Comment: try use tab instead of space

Comment: On the Console it works. But actually im copying the string to clipboard and then inserting it with ctrl + v to whatsapp and other chatrooms.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because most fonts do not have the same character width, try to use a monospaced font.

Answer (score -2):

This is impossible.  You can measure the width of the string in the font you're going to use and add spaces until you get close but the odds are there will be no combination that makes them exactly the same--on average the best solution will be off by 1/4 of the width of a space.

If you want this truly correct you will have to draw the strings separately.

Comment: Are you aware of monospaced fonts?

Comment: @mason Yeah, but they are so rarely used.

Comment: They're used all the time, particularly in situations like this one.